# How to convert string to Xpath in Xquery function (BaseX)

Tags: xpath, xquery, basex

I am writing Xquery function for BaseX which gets one of arguments as name of the element node. This name is then used in Xpath, but in general I cannot convert string to element.

This is how the method looks like

```
declare function prefix:getElementWithValue($root as document-node()?, $elem as xs:string?, $minVal as xs:float?, $maxVal as xs:float?)
as element()*

{ 
  let $e := element {$elem} {""}
  for $x in $root//SUBELEM
  return if ($x//$e/@ATTRIB>=$minVal and $x//$e/@ATTRIB<=$maxVal) then ($x)
};
```

and the call

```
return prefix:getElementWithValue($db, "SomeElem", 10.0, 10.0)
```

and I am getting empty response from that. If I replace the `$x//$e` with `$x//SomeElem` it returns proper response. From the QueryPlan I see that the `$e` is treated as literal value. XPATH is not `$x//SomeElem/@ATTRIB` but `$x//$e/@ATTRIB`

So my question is how to covert string to type that can be used in XPATH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XQuery does not have a standard function to evaluate a dynamically-constructed XPath expression.

Many XQuery processors offer some kind of extension function that does this, however. For example, BaseX offers query:eval():

https://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Module#xquery:eval

Note that variables in XQuery represent values, not fragments of expression text. Your expression `$x//$e/@ATTRIB` is equivalent to `$x//"SomeElem"/@ATTRIB`, which is quite different from `$x//SomeElem/@ATTRIB`.

If you know that `$elem` will always be an element name, then you can write `$x//*[name()=$e]/@ATTRIB`. But take care over namespaces.